# FindResource 1813 error RC_DATA

Tags: c++, c, winapi, resources

I am trying to get .png image from resource file.

```
res.rc
    TEST_BKG RC_DATA "img\\mainwnd_bkg.png"
```

-

```
main.c
    HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(NULL,(LPCSTR)"TEST_BKG", RT_RCDATA);
```

But I have 1813 error: ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND

---

I created new file and tryed again with BITMAP:

```
1 BITMAP "img/mainwnd_bkg.bmp"
2 RC_DATA "img/mainwnd_bkg.png"
```

Src:

```
int main()
{
    HRSRC   hRsrc = FindResource(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), BITMAP);
    if (!hRsrc)
        printf ("err");
    hRsrc = FindResource(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(2), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!hRsrc)
        printf ("err2");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And I get only "err2".

Comment: Make the question clear

Comment: I rolled your edit back. You completely change the question. Let's deal with the question that you asked please.

Comment: Regarding your edit, this looks like fake code. `FindResource(..., ..., BITMAP)`. Are you sure about that third parameter.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I know, but why it cant load a RC_DATA, when BITMAP data loaded?

Comment: I already explained that in my answer hours ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error condition means that there is no resource with that combination of ID and type in the module that you specified.

The most likely explanation is that you are compiling with `UNICODE` defined. As such,  the `FindResource` macro expands to `FindResourceW`. That would explain why you elected to cast the 8 bit string. Presumably the compiler objected and you decided to use a cast.

If that is so, the cast is wrong. The cast that you used doesn't change what the string is, it just tells the compiler to suppress type checking. In effect, you are lying to the compiler by telling it that you are passing one type of data when in fact you supply a different type of data. As a broad rule, you should avoid casting.

Fix your code by passing a wide string:

```
HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(NULL, L"TEST_BKG", RT_RCDATA);
```

You might prefer to be explicit about the function you call and write it like this:

```
HRSRC hRsrc = FindResourceW(NULL, L"TEST_BKG", RT_RCDATA);
```

Other plausible explanations are that you did not link the compiled resource, or that the compiled resource is somehow missing your `RCDATA` resource, or that the module handle supplied to `FindResource` is not correct. You might use a resource viewer to look at the content of the final executable file.

Comment: And what should I do if I try to use variable, instead of string constant? (L"TEST_BKG")

Comment: @Indev29 if you mean you use a numeric id, then `MAKEINTRESOURCE(YOUR_ID_HERE)`. If not, then you need to elaborate on what you mean by "variable" You mean a *changeable* argument var?

Comment: @WhozCraig, I tryed with a numeric id, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: And yes, I mean changeable argument var.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether the resource ID is constant or variable. Regarding your edit, the return value is telling you that there is no resource of that type/id in your module.